# Is there any way to set cell's height after it's components loads but before it displays?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with one custom prototype `cell`. This `cell` has three `labels` (title, price, details), where each of them loads it's text using `CoreData`, so their height is not constant.

`heightForRow atIndexPath` is executed before `cellForRow atIndexPath`, so I can set only one height for all cells. But I need them all to have different size.
What I have tried is in `cellForRow atIndexPath` I get all label's height and deliver it to `tableView.rowHeight`. Unfortunately, it sets all cells to have the same height.

**My question is:**
Is there any method or a way to set each cell's height separately, depending on how many space it needs to display all labels inside?

Comment: Did you try any approach from internet?

Comment: This is ranked as one of the most popular questions in the iOS tag in SO. Search for How to set automatic dimensions for cell and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Actually, I've tried research described by two of you, but couldn't find any satisfying answer, so there's where my question comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in view did load

```
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; // set to whatever your "average" cell height is
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't an answer in my case. It stretched cell's heigh to almost full screen. I have checked my constraints in storyboard if any of them in prototype cell is not making rowHeight so big, but they weren't. Still don't know why they went so big.

Answer (score 0):

What I made was:
- set constraints from scratch (all item's borders to cell's content view)
- used as suggested by @rv7284: 
`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
with one difference - not in `viewDidLoad` but in `viewWillAppear`.
All labels have they're width and height after they load some text and will be placed in RAM.